ApacheDS /instances/default/run has been locked by another directory service Error During ApacheDS Startup and `.dirservice.lock` file
I have an ApacheDS server which stopped accepting connection for apparently no reason.
It could not be stopped with ./apacheds.sh stop.
It had to be killed with fuser -k 10389/tcp.
After this whenever it is was started, it gave

/instances/default/run has been locked by another directory service

error in the apacheds.out / log file
The fix is to delete the .dirservice.lock file in /instances/default/ directory as mentioned here
I could not find any information about the .dirservice.lock file after searching.
What is this file? and what is it used for?
If anyone has encountered such a situation and can throw some light on this.
